# ¿Como puedo sacar la ultima fecha de varios registros diferentes?

Tags: mysql, sql

quisiera saber como puedo sacar la ultima fecha de registros diferentes, es decir que si tengo una tabla donde habrá datos que se repitan entonces me gustaría sacar por lo menos la ultima fecha de uno de esos registros, ejemplo:
Supongamos que tengo la siguiente tabla donde se repetirá constantemente el id_producto

| id | id_producto | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-07 13:53:12 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-05-10 09:30:43 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-05-18 14:46:15 |

lo que yo realmente quiero sacar de la consulta es lo siguiente:

| id_producto | Fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-10 09:30:43 |
| 2 | 2021-05-18 14:46:15 |

el producto con el id 1 se repitió 2 veces pero solo quiero traer la ultima fecha la cual hay registro de ese producto y también mantener la ultima fecha que hay del otro producto.
Intenté utilizando `max(fecha)` pero esta lo que hacía realmente es traer la ultima fecha de toda la columna que en este caso sería `2021-05-18 14:46:15`

¿existe alguna función en mysql que me permita realizar esto? ¿O debo idear un case, o alguna condición que me permita traerme los datos como quiero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes agrupar por `id_producto` para que te muestra la máxima (última) fecha de cada producto.

```
SELECT id_producto, MAX(Fecha) AS Fecha FROM tabla GROUP BY id_producto
```